# Unable to work with "of" class of "rxjs"

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have written `ValueService` class like below.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class ValueService {
    protected value = 'real value';
    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    getObservableValue() {
        return of('Observable value');
    }

    getPromiseValue() {
        return Promise.resolve('Promise value');
    }

    getObservableDelayValue() {
        //return of('Observable delay value').pipe(delay(100));
        return of('Observable delay value').pipe(delay(1000));
    }
}
```

But, getting below error and unable to move ahead.

**ERROR in src/app/demo/demo.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"H:/Ashok/JasmineLearnings/JasminePractice/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'of'.**

Searched in google, but no luck. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem as I don't have much support from my colleagues.

Comment: You have to import of as so.
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

Comment: what version of rxjs are you using? are you sure that the error is coming from this snippet and not somewhere else in your code base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

The error is very clear. There is no exported `'of'` operator in `'rxjs'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there anyway for to know that "of" class can be available under "rxjs/observable", and "delay" class can be available under "rxjs/operators"?

Comment: Check here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/
If you select an operator, there is always an example, how to import it

Answer (score 0):

Try importing:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, If u are using the rxjs first time then I would suggest checking the `package.json` for `rxjs` dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
```

then do a `npm cache clean` and `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do several steps :
1. You can use

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

on the place of

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

2. a.) Go to the workspace  and then Project Folder then access Node_modules and check if rxjs exists or not if exist then check observable files are there or not. If all the files are present then delete the whole rxjs folder

eg: D drive\Sublime_Workspace\MyAngularPoject\node_modules\rxjs 
b.)open the command prompt on your Project location and type the following code:
npm `install rxjs` and hit enter
c.) Run project then check if problem solved .
d.)You can also install rxjs compat on same command prompt  and type following code

```
npm install rxjs-compat
```

hit enter and repeat step d